# Inline coding control's property

Tags: asp.net

IS it possilbe to inline code a porperty like Font-bold of control like linkbutton?

> Font-Bold="<%=(Display==1)?
>   true:false%>"

this doesn't work.

> Cannot create an object of type
>   'System.Boolean' from its string
>   representation '<%=(Display==2)?
>   true:false%>' for the 'Bold'
>   property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't use inline code on attributes of Runat="server" elements.

Use the PreRender event of the page.  Assuming the linkbutton has ID="myLinkButton" :-

```
 myLinkButton.Font.Bold = (Display == 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can only do this with data binding expressions:

`Font-Bold="<%# (Display==1)? true:false %>"`

Note the <%# instead of the <%=

And then you have to call DataBind() on the control or one of its containers.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with single quotes.

E.g.

```
Font-Bold='<%....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this functionality with a custom ExpressionBuilder, but it doesn't come standard.

With the [CodeExpressionBuilder](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/09/The-CodeExpressionBuilder.aspx) example you can use the syntax `Text="<%$ Code: DateTime.Now %>"`